# how to format a url to be live

Tags: php, html, url, anchor

I have been working on trying to teach myself programming and have come stuck on a simple problem ,

the line I am working with is

```
echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>";
```

only in the database {mysql} it is in plain text under the column 'website' , I have been trying to work out how to make the row website clickable for the whole table,

```
i have tried  <href ="echo "<td>" . $row['website'] . "</td>"";
```

I have tried searching  the web for an answer , only i dont seem to be able to phrase the question for the right results.

thank you .

---

I also tried

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leader");
echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>id</th> <th>Club</th> <th>Website</th> <th>Club Badge</th> </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>"."<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['club'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['website' ] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a class=\"mylink\" href=\"" . $row['website'] . "\">" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

but still got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/a6332763/public_html/res.php on line 29`

UPDATE......... Have now got link to show in right box only its adding the sites url in-front of the links url, here is the code , minus mysqul connection .

```
    <?php


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leader");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Club</th>
<th>Website</th>
<th>Club Badge Url</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "<tr>"."<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['club'] . "</td>";



echo "<td><a class=\"mylink\" href=\"" . $row['website'] . "\">" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";


 echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";




mysql_close($con);
?> 
<html>
<body>
<a href="res.php">Link text</a> 
Click on <a href="http://www.sumsitehere.com">this link</a> to run your first PHP script. 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your question about making an entire table row clickable? Because your title doesn't seem to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply meagar, i used the term 'row' because thats what it says in the code $row ,  where as when it prints out , i am hopping the whole column 'website' is live,

Comment: You don't need echo "<tr>"."<tr>"; just echo "<tr>";

Comment: got the links clickable now, only they dont go anywhere ,and all the links now look like " mysite.com/www.outputsite.com " insted of "www.outputsite.com "

Answer (score 3):

Anchor tags (`<a>`) cannot contain table rows or cells. To make the entire row clickable, you must bind an `onclick` handler with JavaScript or wrap the contents of each individual `<td>` element with its own `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a way to make a link out the area of the row where your links is do the following:

In the **PHP** file:

```
echo "<td><a class=\"mylink\" href=\"" . $row['website'] . "\">" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";
```

In the **CSS** file:

```
.mylink{display:block;}
```

That should do it.

Comment: This is going to result in a tag with no content, and no `</a>`.

Comment: thanks redhatlab, not got to CSS yet , understand that it controls all the sites formatting and could be very helpful and save loads of time later on.

Comment: have made a .css file called CSS.css and have tried the above , am now getting `website` in one box {unclickable} and then again in the next column under a different heading { yet its clickable only it now adds the site url its on and the url of where to go to [eg  http://mysite.net/www.yahoo.com   thus results in a no go link] and the data that's spouse to be in that column is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: ` needed to delete a line of text has stopped the extra box.

Comment: Why not just use single quotes within the string instead of escaped double quotes? Also, since the point of double quote strings in PHP is variable substitution, use the {} syntax instead of breaking the string to concatenate. For example `echo "<a class='mylink' href='{$row['website']}'>";`

Answer (score 0):

Fill the appropriate `onclick` attribute with JavaScript code to open the new location.

Comment: While technically correct, that's not likely to be much help to someone that's new at this.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams , wots JavaScript ? {lol} an 'onclick` popup formatting thinggy would be helpful only dont get them with notepad.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the a regular link inside a table cell what you want is

```
<td><a href="<?= $row['website'] ?>"><?= $row['website'] ?></a></td>
```

If you were actually trying to make the entire table row clickable, you need to use a javascript redirect set on the table row:

```
<tr onClick="window.location='<?= $row['website'] ?>'">
    <td><?= $row['website'] ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I will recommend you to use the full tag for php. Use <?php instead of just <?.

Comment: @redhatlab - You have fun typing that out every time then.  Some of us have better things to do.

Comment: I have tried the above line as a straight copy n paste and also including echo before and with ; and sum extra "  get the same sort of error    ***  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/a6332763/public_html/res.php on line 29 ***

Comment: @simples - it's hard to say what the problem would be without seeing the code around it

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leader");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Club</th>
<th>Website</th>
<th>Club Badge</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  
  {
  echo "<tr>"."<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['club'] . "</td>";
  
echo "<td>" . $row['website' ] . "</td>"; 

echo "<td><a class=\"mylink\" href=\"" . $row['website'] . "\">" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>";


 echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";




mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: @simples - it's really hard to read code in comments.  I still don't see the source of the parse error.  Try updating your question with the entire page's code if it's not too big.

Comment: @bemace there's no reason to assume that the server on which simples is working has short tags enabled. Many hosts do not enable short tags.

Comment: @Alex - simples is free to use whichever style he prefers, as is everyone else.  I was just responding to be told how to write *my* code.

Comment: He can't use them if his host does not have short tags enabled in their php.ini. I'm not sure whether short_open_tags can be enabled at run time or not.